# Excel-VBA Red color labeled

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to make a red label appear on my form and can not. I have tried changing the property to RGB and HEX and just get errors. Is there a way to get a property value to make my label RGB(200, 0, 0)? I am unaware of how the value in the property areas is developed.

This is the only way I can make a red label:

```
Private Sub Label13_Click()
 Label13.BackColor = RGB(200, 0, 0)
End Sub
```

I have to click the label to make it red. Is there a way to use code to make it red when the form starts? Or perhaps generate a value for the property? Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: One possible way is to check the decimal value returned by RGB function (for `RGB(200, 0, 0)` it's simply `200`)  and enter this value in properties window. It will be automatically converted to HEX BGR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Initialize` event for the form instead of putting the event on a `Click` event.

Here is an example with the form named `UserForm`.  Use the dropdowns to select the form and then the `Initialize` event.

[image: form events]

You can also just set the color in the properties if you know this is the color you want.

[image: label properties]

Comment: How did you bring that window up? I am not able to find a button for that. The one with the colors

Comment: Once in the VBA editor, hit `F4` or on the menu `View->Properties Window`

Comment: Figured it out thank you. I had mines in Dock mode. Thank you a lot

Comment: The F4 way is even better of what I found.